# TypeError on simple example of using add-on layer WeightNormalization

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, typeerror, google-colaboratory, layer

The following simple code gives error:

```
 x = np.random.rand(1, 10, 10, 1)
 dense = addon_layers.WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10), data_init=False)
 y = dense(x)
 y.shape`

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-47-a2d44c85c018> in <module>
       2 
       3 x = np.random.rand(1, 10, 10, 1)
 ----> 4 dense = addon_layers.WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
       5 y = dense(x)
       6 y.shape

 2 frames
 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow_addons/layers/wrappers.py in             __init__(self, layer, data_init, **kwargs)
      57 
      58     @typechecked
 ---> 59     def __init__(self, layer: tf.keras.layers, data_init: bool = True, **kwargs):
      60         super().__init__(layer, **kwargs)
      61         self.data_init = data_init
 
 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/typeguard/_functions.py in check_argument_types(memo)
     111             value = memo.arguments[argname]
     112             try:
 --> 113                 check_type_internal(value, expected_type, memo=memo)
     114             except TypeCheckError as exc:
     115                 qualname = qualified_name(value, add_class_prefix=True)
 
 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/typeguard/_checkers.py in check_type_internal(value,      annotation, memo)
     668             return
     669 
 --> 670     if not isinstance(value, origin_type):
     671         raise TypeCheckError(f"is not an instance of {qualified_name(origin_type)}")
     672 
 
 TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

The Dense layer independently is not giving any error. So, the problem seems with the WeightNormalization. Also, I am working on colab.

Comment: Seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2819) in TensorFlow addons.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not importing the `WeightNormalization` in correct way. There is no module named `addon_layers` in `tensorflow_addons`. Please try again using code below in Google Colab:

```
x = np.random.rand(1, 10, 10, 1)
dense = tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10), data_init=False)
y = dense(x)
y.shape
```

Output:

```
TensorShape([1, 10, 10, 10])
```